# Cannot find file in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In the latest versions of PhpStorm (2016.2.1) and up I am getting every so often popups with a message: 'Cannot find file'.

I checked the log file and saw these lines.

```
2016-08-02 17:10:20,768 [29864274]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - External command line: 
2016-08-02 17:10:20,768 [29864274]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - Dir: /home/jigal/. 
2016-08-02 17:10:20,768 [29864274]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - -U 
2016-08-02 17:10:20,768 [29864274]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - root 
2016-08-02 17:10:20,768 [29864274]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - -o 
2016-08-02 17:10:20,768 [29864274]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - comm
```

I really have no idea how to fix this. Any Suggestions?

---

At the moment I am using EAP. The latest is:

> PhpStorm 2016.2.1 Build #PS-162.1447.5, built on July 19, 2016
>   Licensed to PhpStorm Evaluator
>   Expiration date: August 28, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Below are some screenshots of the popups:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you turned off all/any plugins? It may be a plugin searching for a file that's not there.

Comment: @Martin I have updated my post with the version I am running. I don't have any plugins installed yet

Comment: What file it cannot find? Show a screenshot of how it looks (that message -- to see the context). After what operation this messages shows up?

Comment: I have added screenshots of the popup. I hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: Need more info. It's not clear where this message comes from (what functionality/plugin is responsible for that). Please share your `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in...). So far it looks like you have created some tool (don't know -- External Tool or File Watcher etc) and provided wrong path there). **P.S.** This is NOT a bug in PhpStorm -- more like misconfiguration from user end. **P.P.S.** And please use `@username` otherwise user will not be informed about your new comment/info

Comment: @LazyOne you can find my idea.log as an attachement to this bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32769. This happened to me after a fresh install of PHP storm

Comment: Since you have created an issue at Issue Tracker ... then devs will have a look at it (no much point discussing it here). I may only suggest to try this: close project in IDE and backup & delete `.idea` subfolder (this project settings). Then open IDE and re-configure that project from scratch (e.g. use `Open` on Welcome screen and point to the project root folder). Does it still keep happening after that as well?